# FileNotFoundException, but file exists in the same level

Tags: java, error-handling, filenotfoundexception, file-not-found

I've created a program, which helds the grades of the pupils, I want to store these grades in a txt file, and when I start the program, import the grades and after the program finished, export the grades. I have the import and exportTo methods in a separate file, and then  I call these methods in the main class. All files are on the same level and there are no syntax errors. But I still get a FileNotFoundException as an error. Here's my import and export code:

```
public void exportTo(String fileName) {
    try (
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fos);
    ) {
        for (Grade grade : mGrades) {
            System.out.printf("New grade" +grade);
            writer.printf("%s|%s%n",grade.getPupil(), grade.getGrade());
        }
    } catch(IOException ioe) {
        System.out.printf("Problem saving %s %n", fileName);
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void importFrom(String fileName) {
    try (
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
    ) {
        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] args = line.split("\\|");
            addGrade(new Grade(args[0], args[1]));
        }
    } catch(IOException ioe) {
        System.out.printf("Problems loading %s %n", fileName);
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: show us your path to files( a.k.a filename)

Comment: You are probably specifying just the file name (not the full path) and the current directory to your program is not the one your input file is in.

Comment: Code seems to be okay, just check your file paths

Comment: Please check the directory where your program is running. Also check if you specified the correct and complete path when writing your file. And verify if you have OS permission in that place.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the fact that your working directory is not set correctly. To get around this issue, do this.

'''

```
System.setProperty("user.dir", YOUR_WORKING_DIRECTORY);
String dir = System.getProperty("user.dir")
```

'''

Then you can pass in the directory name to your function.

Or if you are using IntelliJ,

1. Click on 'Run'
2. Go to 'Edit Configurations'
3. Look for the 'Working directory' field
4. Change that to the directory you are working on.